# setTimout function # tag?

Tags: jquery

Can someone please help?  I have some jQuery code which is working perfectly, however there is an element within it which is: "#"+ and I don't understand what it does. Please see below JS.

```
setTimeout (function() {
     $("#"+toneId2nd).animate({ backgroundColor: 'red'}).animate({ b    ackgroundColor: 'white'}, 4000);
    play_multi_sound('tone-'+toneId2nd);
}, 1000);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `# is for -> $("#"+elementId)` and `. is for -> $("."+elementClass)`

Comment: `toneId2nd` is just a supplied variable.

Comment: #  is selector  = > Selects the element with id="<value of toneId2nd>"  [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myElement').animate({ backgroundColor: 'red'}).animate({ backgroundColor: 'white'}, 4000);
play_multi_sound('tone-myElement');
```

is the same as:

```
var toneId2nd = 'myElement';
$('#'+toneId2nd).animate({ backgroundColor: 'red'}).animate({ backgroundColor: 'white'}, 4000);
play_multi_sound('tone-'+toneId2nd);
```

`toneId2nd` is just a supplied variable.

jQuery uses CSS selectors to grab elements.

I suggest you start [here](http://learn.jquery.com/) if you need more help with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

it is the Id of the Element 
$('#ElementId')

toneId2nd is some kind of element ID

Ex: $('#mydiv')

Answer (score 0):

See the answer on this question : [using variables within a jquery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823339/using-variables-within-a-jquery-selector)

And maybe try to do some research before asking? ;)